# What is "W external" and "W internal" in Energy conservation law?

Tags: forces, newtonian-gravity, energy-conservation, potential

When I solve the energy conservation problem, I am confused when I have to make the term positive or negative.

For example, someone throws a ball right up to the ground with velocity, $v$. The ball will go up to height, $h$, where velocity is 0.

Then,the equation is 
$$\int_0^h mg\,dh + \frac12mv^2$$ or $$-\int_0^h mg\,dh + \frac12mv^2$$
Is it related with something like "$W_{external} - W_{internal}$"? If yes, then what does external and internal mean?

I don't want the answer like "hey, Kinetic energy become potential energy, so $mgh = \frac12 mv^2$". This is right, just in this case. I need a consistent method that works any problems.

Comment: Why are the integrals there?

Comment: sorry. Not h, it is vector dh. And the range of integral is from 0 to certain height.

Comment: Think about the total energy. Does it go *up* or *down* when a ball with fixed kinetic energy is moved up (relative to the center of the earth)? This should fix your sign.